# Custom Tab Bar with details view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, tabbarcontroller

I'm creating a custom tab bar based on this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

Everything is fine but when I want to segue from a certain view controller to its "details view", the details view covers the bottom bar with menu. This behaviour is logical as I'm pushing a new view controller but how would I have to do it in order to keep the bottom bar always visible and functional?

I'm using segue for this because I need to pass some data. I need custom bar because the functionality and the look would be very difficult to implement using the Apple's one.

Any tips or suggestions?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here all "tab" are working well but when you tap on a row I navigate to "details" view

[image]

[image: Details view]

In the details view, bottom bar is not visible.

Comment: did you set the contentView mentioned in step 9

Comment: yes, I've got all tutorial's steps working fine. The issue is with details view, which is not covered in the tutorial :(

Comment: can you post some screenshot of your problem?

Comment: I edited my post to include images

Comment: set your customBar.layer.zPostion = 1 or try your customView bringSubview(toFront:)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help, even if it would, content in the table view inside Details view would be under the bar.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false` for the details view?

Comment: I'm not using UITabBarController. It is all based on UIViewControllers and my bottom bar is just a UIView. There is no hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property

Comment: Container View is nothing more than a UIView and I use it for displaying UIViewControllers for each tab. The question could be how to navigate from view controller in container view to another view controller with segue so that both have the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Instead of calling
      `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailsViewSegue", sender: self)`

in

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`
I add DetailsView view to the hierarchy like so:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let detailsView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("contactDetailsView")
addChildViewController(detailsView)
detailsView.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.superview!.frame.height)
self.view.addSubview(detailsView.view)
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
       detailsView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.superview!.frame.height)
}
detailsView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

then when user taps on the back arrow I do:

```
 @IBAction func goBackButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
        self.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { 
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
            }) { (completed) in
                if completed {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.removeFromParentViewController()
            }
        }
    }
```